# asp.net mvc overload with jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller, webgrid

I have two controllers. First I get webgrid. I want search database with jquery and enter search area. Then run 2nd controller but page is not new. Page is same previous state.

```
This is view:



<h2>NewGrid</h2>

<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @*<tr style="visibility:hidden"><td><input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value=@ViewBag.Code.ToString() /></td></tr>*@
        <tr>
            @For Each col As ServiceReference1.Column In ViewBag.ColumnList

                @<td>
                    <input class="search" id=@col.columnName type="text" value="gün" name=@col.columnName style="border-width:1px;width:@col.columnWidth.ToString()px;" />
                </td>
            Next
        </tr>
    </table>
@Code
    Dim grid As WebGrid = New WebGrid(Model)
    Dim columnsL As List(Of WebGridColumn) = New List(Of WebGridColumn)
    For Each col As ServiceReference1.Column In ViewBag.ColumnList
        columnsL.Add(grid.Column(columnName:=col.columnName, header:=col.columnCaptionValue, format:=Function(item) New MvcHtmlString("<div style='width:" + col.columnWidth.ToString() + "px;'>" +
               item(col.columnCaptionValue) +
               "</div>")))
    Next
End Code

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:="table table-striped table-bordered", columns:=columnsL)
</div>

    @ViewBag.GridSqlQuery

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('body').on('keyup', '.search', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              alert('enter key');
              var data = { columnName: $(this).attr('id'), columnValue: $(this).val(), columnSql:"@ViewBag.GridSqlQuery" };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/NewGrid",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function () {
                        alert("arandı");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is controller: 
1. action run when page is start:

```
 Function NewGrid() As ActionResult
        Dim g As ServiceReference1.Grid = New Grid
        Dim client As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        g = client.GetGridInformation("lst_afhFTR")
        Dim column As List(Of ServiceReference1.Column)
        column = g.columnList.ToList
        Dim columnName As List(Of String) = g.columnList.Select(Function(f) f.columnName).ToList()
        client.Close()
        Dim client3 As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        Dim result As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = client3.GetTableOl(g.gridCode).ToList()
        'WebGrid içine gönderilecek data oluşturulması 
        Dim data = New List(Of ExpandoObject)()
        For Each Pairs In result
            Dim row = New ExpandoObject()
            For Each Pair In Pairs
                DirectCast(row, IDictionary(Of String, Object)).Add(Pair.Key, Pair.Value)
            Next
            data.Add(row)
        Next
        ViewBag.ColumnList = g.columnList
        ViewBag.GridSqlQuery = g.gridCode
        Return View(data)
    End Function
```

2nd action run when you want search and I have search input text:

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function NewGrid(columnName As String, columnValue As String, columnSql As String) As ActionResult
        Dim g As ServiceReference1.Grid = New Grid
        Dim client As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        g = client.GetGridInformation("lst_afhFTR")
        Dim column As List(Of ServiceReference1.Column)
        column = g.columnList.ToList
        client.Close()

        columnSql = columnSql.ToString() + " where 1 = 1"
        columnSql = columnSql + " and " + columnName + " Like '%" + columnValue + "%'"
        Dim client3 As ServiceReference1.Service1Client = New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        Dim result As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = client3.GetSearchData(columnSql).ToList()
        'WebGrid içine gönderilecek data oluşturulması 
        Dim data = New List(Of ExpandoObject)()
        For Each Pairs In result
            Dim row = New ExpandoObject()
            For Each Pair In Pairs
                DirectCast(row, IDictionary(Of String, Object)).Add(Pair.Key, Pair.Value)
            Next
            data.Add(row)
        Next
        ViewBag.ColumnList = g.columnList
        ViewBag.GridSqlQuery = columnSql
        Return View(data)
    End Function
```